# VBA Matrix addition after previous multiplication

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add two matrices, after I recieved one of the two by a matrix multiplication. The Formular I want to calculate is: ((TS x TI) + TI) x PK = TK

```
Dim TS_Matrix As Variant, TI_Matrix As Variant, Dummy_Matrix As Variant, PK_Matrix As Variant, TK_Matrix As Variant

'Read matrices
TS_Matrix = Worksheets(1).Range("B2:E5")
TI_Matrix = Worksheets(2).Range("B2:E5")
PK_Matrix = Worksheets(3).Range("B2:B5")

'Calculation
Dummy_Matrix = Application.MMult(TS_Matrix, TI_Matrix)
Dummy_Matrix = Dummy_Matrix + TI_Matrix
TK_Matrix = Application.MMult(Dummy_Matrix, PK_Matrix)

'Write
Worksheets(4).Range("B2:B5") = TK_Matrix
```

Without the addition it works perfectly. How do I fix it? The following line gives me a

> run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch.

```
Dummy_Matrix = Dummy_Matrix + TI_Matrix
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check the data type of what you are adding..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add 2 matrices like this `Dummy_Matrix = Dummy_Matrix + TI_Matrix` because VBA doesn't support to add 2 arrays out of the box. Instead you would need to loop through all elements of the array to add each by each.

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMatrixAdd()
    Dim MatrixA As Variant
    Dim MatrixB As Variant
    Dim MatrixOut As Range 'note output must be a range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'adjust to your sheet
        MatrixA = .Range("A1:B5")
        MatrixB = .Range("D1:E5")
        Set MatrixOut = .Range("G1:H5")
    End With

    MatrixOut = AddMatrices(MatrixA, MatrixB)
End Sub


Public Function AddMatrices(MatrixA As Variant, MatrixB As Variant) As Variant
    'matrices must be of the same size
    If LBound(MatrixA, 1) <> LBound(MatrixB, 1) Or _
       LBound(MatrixA, 2) <> LBound(MatrixB, 2) Or _
       UBound(MatrixA, 1) <> UBound(MatrixB, 1) Or _
       UBound(MatrixA, 2) <> UBound(MatrixB, 2) Then
        GoTo SIZE_ERROR
    End If


    Dim MatrixOut As Variant
    ReDim MatrixOut(LBound(MatrixA, 1) To UBound(MatrixA, 1), LBound(MatrixA, 2) To UBound(MatrixA, 2))

    'matrix addition
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(MatrixA, 1) To UBound(MatrixA, 1)
        For j = LBound(MatrixA, 2) To UBound(MatrixA, 2)
            MatrixOut(i, j) = MatrixA(i, j) + MatrixB(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    AddMatrices = MatrixOut

    Exit Function
SIZE_ERROR:
    AddMatrices = "Matrices must be of the same size"
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Very instructive, liked the clear structured example :-)